# Laravel why get element by id is not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, laravel-8

When i am entering hard coded id in Laravel controller, i am able to get data but when
i enter same value in text box data i am getting error.

**`working Laravel controller` which shows value against id 123:**

```
public function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        $files = Files::where('file_code','=','123')->first();
        return response()->json([
            'files'=> $files,      
          ], 200);
          
    }
```

**Not working Laravel controller:**

```
 public function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        $file_code=Files::find($request->id);
        $files = Files::where($file_code,'=','file_code')->get();
        return response()->json([
            'files'=> $files,      
          ], 200);
          
    }
```

**error in log:**

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `files` where `` = file_code)
```

**VIEW:**

```
<input v-model="state.file_code"  type="text" placeholder="Enter file code">

<textarea v-model="state.files.text_data" placeholder="text appear here "></textarea>

<button  @click="getdata" class="bg-green-800  rounded p-2 mb-5 text-white  " >RECEIVE</button>
```

**Get function:**

```
function getdata(){
   axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-data',{
     id: state.file_code,
   })
   .then(response=>{
     state.files=response.data.files;   
   });
 }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('get-data',[FilesController::class,'getdata']);
```

Comment: why are you trying to search a column named after the value of `$file_code` (which could be `null` or an object)? isn't there a specific column you should be searching?

Comment: i want to get data against id, eg. 123 as done in working controller above.

Comment: i thought $request->id is getting id from view.

Comment: what is the primary key for this table/model? is it `id` or `file_code`? .... if the first example works why don't you just remove the hardcoded value and use the input there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

Route:

```php
Route::get('get-data',[FilesController::class,'getdata']);
```

Controller:

```php
$file_code=Files::find($request->id);
$files = Files::where($file_code,'=','file_code')->get();
```

Your route doesn't specify an `{id}` variable, so `$request->id` in your controller will always be `null`.

Then you're trying to get a `Files` object with `Files::find(null)`, which will also always return `null`, i.e. `$file_code` is `null`.

Then you're looking for another `Files` object with `Files::where(null,'=','file_code')->get();`. This line will return all `Files` object where the `null` or `""` column is `"file_code"`.

What you probably want to do is something like:

Route:

```php
Route::get('get-data/{id}',[FilesController::class,'getdata']);
```

Controller:

```php
$files = Files::find($request->id);
```